# Blogdown: Individual publication content not displaying

Tags: blogdown

I'm using this theme in RStudio Blogdown and Netlify on a MacOS. After updating blowdown to v.1.2, the site for individual publication content stopped displaying any information. The html for individual publications in public is blank.

I also noticed that duplicates of the `featured.png` for individual publications are created after running `blogdown::serve_site()`. Though I can't see how this could be related to the issue above, I tried deleting duplicate images and no changes.

I have not managed to find anyone reporting the same issue (sorry if I missed it). I checked the dates and potential errors in the index.md publication files, and execute `hugo -v`. I have not found any issue.

Any pointers to resolve these issues would be very appreciated.

For a reproducible example:

Site: https://www.franciscorowe.com

Site repo (served from here): GitHub - fcorowe/franciscorowe.github.io

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `blogdown::check_site()`?

Comment: I did try that. Inspecting my GitHub commits, I managed to determine that the issue started after I updated `blogdown` but  I could't figure out the issue. I ended up creating a new site from scratch using the latest version of `blogdown` and it's now working fine. https://github.com/fcorowe/franciscorowe/commits/main. BTW, @YihuiXie thanks for that awesome package!

Comment: I'm sorry for the trouble! If you have a version of the source of the old site, I'll be happy to investigate the problem. If not, next time please feel free to point me to the source repo (instead of the output repo) and let me know which commit is broken. Thank you!

Comment: Here is the old repo [link](https://github.com/fcorowe/franciscorowe.github.io). Sorry for not being very helpful here, but I don't exactly recall the exact commit which caused to the issue. I recall it was around Dec 2019 now. It took me some time to post the issue as I wanted to explore it myself. I managed to find the time for this only recently. Not sure how widespread this issue may be - though I recall reading related issues on the `blogdown` GitHub account. As I said, sorry, I know this is not very precise; hence, useful. So feel free to ignore this. Thanks.

Comment: No worries at all! Please feel free to file an issue to the blogdown repo on Github as soon as you discover a problem. Thanks!